# pygame.mixer.Sound playing 2 times in a row

Tags: python, pygame

```
        if click[0] == 1:
            fabian_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('my_sound.wav')
            pygame.mixer.Sound.stop
            pygame.mixer.Sound.play(my_sound, 1)
            pygame.mixer.Sound.set_volume(my_sound, 0.1)
```

Hi guys so I've made a simple code that if you click on image, my_sound.wav appears but theres one problem. Every time I click on image, my_sound.wav plays one time and after 2-3 sec again even if I dont click anything. Also it sounds like its slow down a bit can anyone help me with that? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sound is repeated 1 time because you set the `loops` argument to `1`.

Look at the [docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Sound.play):

> The loops argument controls how many times the sample will be repeated after being played the first time. A value of 5 means that the sound will be played once, then repeated five times, and so is played a total of six times. The default value (zero) means the Sound is not repeated, and so is only played once.

So if you set `loops` to `1`, it will be repeated once.

Also, in the code you have posted:
- you load `my_sound.wav`, but never use it.
- The line `pygame.mixer.Sound.stop` also does nothing.
- Instead of `pygame.mixer.Sound.play(my_sound, 1)`, you should call the method on the object itself, like `my_sound.play()` (note I also removed the `loops` argument). The same is true for the next line.